# Musaf for Rosh Hodesh Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, musaf

Something that has puzzled me for decades, and I'm reminded of it during holidays and rosh hodesh-shabbat:
Why (except for the first line) is the beginning rubric for the mussaf's "sanctification of the day" for holidays and rosh hodesh-shabbat identical?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but I got this answer to a question I asked and it might help out https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99714/1362

Comment: Possibly similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86117/759

Comment: I have to read it again to be sure, but I believe the זאב יטרף claims that the essential difference between the holiday of ראש חודש and the other holidays is that the other holidays have an extra level of קדושה in the prohibition of labor, so if you have ראש חודש combined with שבת it upgrades us to a yom-tov level kedusha, with the appropriate yom-tov style mussaf to go with it. (Or something like that.)